The sample doesnt work which is provided by Microsft offically
The sample doesnt work which is provided by Microsft offically. Does Fast UI deprecated? Oh my god, Bill Gaisi, IE6.0... Everything is BUG
https://github.com/microsoft/fast/tree/master/examples/design-system-tutorial
ERROR in ./src/main.ts
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/ts-loader/index.js):
Error: Debug Failure. False expression: Non-string value passed to `ts.resolveTypeReferenceDirective`, likely by a wrapping package working with an outdated `resolveTypeReferenceDirectives` signature. This is probably not a problem in TS itself.
    at Object.resolveTypeReferenceDirective (C:\Users\chris\my\project\Y-Platform\fast\examples\design-system-tutorial\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:43500:18)
    at C:\Users\chris\my\project\Y-Platform\fast\examples\design-system-tutorial\node_modules\ts-loader\dist\servicesHost.js:613:77
    at C:\Users\chris\my\project\Y-Platform\fast\examples\design-system-tutorial\node_modules\ts-loader\dist\servicesHost.js:131:142
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Object.resolveTypeReferenceDirectives (C:\Users\chris\my\project\Y-Platform\fast\examples\design-system-tutorial\node_modules\ts-loader\dist\servicesHost.js:131:125)
    at actualResolveTypeReferenceDirectiveNamesWorker (C:\Users\chris\my\project\Y-Platform\fast\examples\design-system-tutorial\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:119382:163)
    at resolveTypeReferenceDirectiveNamesWorker (C:\Users\chris\my\project\Y-Platform\fast\examples\design-system-tutorial\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:119682:26)
    at processTypeReferenceDirectives (C:\Users\chris\my\project\Y-Platform\fast\examples\design-system-tutorial\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:121185:31)
    at findSourceFileWorker (C:\Users\chris\my\project\Y-Platform\fast\examples\design-system-tutorial\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:121070:21)
    at findSourceFile (C:\Users\chris\my\project\Y-Platform\fast\examples\design-system-tutorial\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:120922:26)
 @ multi ./src/main.ts app[0]

